# Python click shell command with arguments

Tags: python, shell, click

I am trying to build a command line interface using click-shell in python but I am unable to figure out how to provide inputs together with the commands. That is, say I have a function/command named `sum`, that requires two inputs `a` and `b`, on cmd how do I invoke `myapp > sum 2 3`? Currently all I have to do is invoke the inputs in the functions themselves.

this works:

```
from click_shell import shell

@shell(prompt='myapp> ', intro='Command me!')
def myapp():
    os.system("cls")

@myapp.command()
def sum():
    a = input('enter num1 > ')
    b = input('enter num2 > ')
    r = float(a) + float(b)
    print(f"{a} + {b} = {r}")
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
@myapp.command()
def sum(a, b):
    print(f"{a} + {b} = {float(a) + float(b)}")
```

such that on CMD all I have to do is:

```
myapp> sum 2 3
:> 2 + 3 = 5
myapp>
```

Anyone who knows how to achieve this please help. Suggestion on better package to use is accepted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting various approaches and one of the attempt was to add `@click.argument` decorator and it worked as I wanted. Here

```
from click_shell import shell
import os, click

@shell(prompt='myapp> ', intro='Hello There! Enter your commands')
def myapp():
    os.system("cls")

@myapp.command()
@click.argument('nums', type=float, nargs=-1)
def add(nums: list[float]):
    print(f"sum = {sum(nums)}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp()
```

any better solution will be accepted